# Cannot install apps on google play

Tags: applications

As the title reads, I cannot install apps. Plenty of space available, shows the downloading bar but does not show the downloaded/remaining bar and does not start downloading at all.

Comment: That's probably a network problem. Are you on WiFi or mobile data?

Comment: Nope, solid wifi connection I setup for myself for home use.

Comment: Clear data and cache of - Google Play Store and Download Manager in Settings>Apps>All apps.

Comment: Also go through questions related to yours in this site.